# In Javascript I want to add a value to an array but in console i have the error "missing ; before statement"

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code:

```
for(var i=0;i<ordini.length;i++){
        var quantitaordineinvio[i] = quantitaordineponte;
    }
```

When I run it I get the error missing ; before statement.
But I just can not figure out what 's wrong . Can you help me?

Comment: What do you think `[i]` means there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var` is for declaring variables. That's not what you're doing inside your loop; inside your loop, you're adding entries to an array. So remove the `var` from it.

If `quantitaordineinvio` hasn't been declared yet, you do want to declare it, just once, above the loop. You also want to initialize it, I'm guessing in this case with an empty array (`[]`):

```
var quantitaordineinvio = [];
for(var i=0;i<ordini.length;i++){
    quantitaordineinvio[i] = quantitaordineponte;
}
```

---

Side note: Your adding the **same value** to the array repeatedly *(just in case that's not what you meant to do)*.

Answer (score 0):

Or just this line in ES6 with a map method :

```
var quantitaordineinvio = ordini.map(item => quantitaordineponte);
```